# Error creating bean with name 'sessionBuilderCustomizer' defined in com.example.betterreadsDataloader.BetterreadsDataloader1Application

Tags: spring-boot, cassandra, datastax-astra

I am creating this spring boot with Cassandra and when trying to do a connection with Cassandra I am getting this error. Please help:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean \
  with name 'sessionBuilderCustomizer' defined in \
  com.example.betterreadsDataloader.BetterreadsDataloader1Application: \
  Bean instantiation via factory method failed; \
  nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: \
  Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer]: \
  Factory method 'sessionBuilderCustomizer' threw exception; \
  nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:953) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at com.example.betterreadsDataloader.BetterreadsDataloader1Application.main(BetterreadsDataloader1Application.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
```

```
package com.example.betterreadsDataloader;

import java.nio.file.Path;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.example.betterreadsDataloader.connection.DataStaxAstraProperties;



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(DataStaxAstraProperties.class)
public class BetterreadsDataloader1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BetterreadsDataloader1Application.class, args);
    }
    @Bean
    public CqlSessionBuilderCustomizer sessionBuilderCustomizer(DataStaxAstraProperties astraProperties) {
        Path bundle = astraProperties.getSecureConnectBundle().toPath();
        return builder -> builder.withCloudSecureConnectBundle(bundle);
    }
    
}
```

```
package com.example.betterreadsDataloader.connection;

import java.io.File;

import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;



@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datastax.astra")
public class DataStaxAstraProperties {

    private File secureConnectBundle;

    public File getSecureConnectBundle() {
        return secureConnectBundle;
    }

    public void setSecureConnectBundle(File secureConnectBundle) {
        this.secureConnectBundle = secureConnectBundle;
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
       keyspace-name: xxx
       username: xxx
       password: xxxx
       schema-action: create-if-not-exists
       request:
        timeout:10s
       connection:
        connect-timeout:10s
        init-query-timeout:10s
        
       
datastax.astra:
     secure-connect-bundle:secure-connect-booktracker.zip
     
astra.db:
   id:xxx
   region:xxx
   namespace:main
   application.token:xxx
```

Comment: Where is this `secure-connect-booktracker.zip` located? If that is part of your application it isn't a file but a resource. A `java.io.File` is a physical file on your file system, if it is packaged inside your `jar` file it isn't a physical file on your file system.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're doing the [BetterReads coding series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LxVGFBRpEFM&list=PLJ5_m4Y8xLkkxfo2Z1Lb0qjXnAZqIWCCZ) from [Java Brains](https://www.youtube.com/c/JavaBrainsChannel).

The `NullPointerException` from `sessionBuilderCustomizer` possibly means that it can't locate your secure connect bundle (SCB). According to Koushik's workshop, you need to place the SCB in the `src/main/resources/` directory of your project.

Check that you've configured your project correctly according to the workshop then try to run the app again. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Eric Thanks for your answer I have double checked it, it is placed in src/main/resources/  directory, not sure why I am getting this error.

Comment: I think Eric is correct the file is not found and `Path bundle = astraProperties.getSecureConnectBundle().toPath();` will get you the NPE, everything else looks good. Try to change from `secure-connect-booktracker.zip` to `src/main/resources/secure-connect-booktracker.zip` you may need to help Spring.

Comment: Also FYI I created a dedicated workshop here https://github.com/datastaxdevs/workshop-betterreads improve the code quite a bit and especially the data loader 400 times faster.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an indentation error to me in your application.yaml where the property astra.db should be `spring.astra.db` and not `astra.db` as a standalone property.

As well as the class `DataStaxAstraProperties` should be annotated with `@Configuration` .

That being said your application.yml should effectively look like this

```
spring:
  data:
    cassandra:
      keyspace-name: xxx
      username: xxx
      password: xxxx
      schema-action: create-if-not-exists
      request:
        timeout: 10s
      connection:
        connect-timeout: 10s
        init-query-timeout: 10s
datastax.astra:
    secure-connect-bundle:secure-connect-booktracker.zip
  astra.db:
      id: xxx
      region: xxx
      namespace: main
      application.token:xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, check your application.yml file. Try using this format.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: betterreads
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          github:
            client-id: 
            client-secret: 
  cassandra:
    keyspace-name: 
    username: 
    password: 
    schema-action: recreate-drop-unused
    request:
      timeout: 10s
    connection:
      connect-timeout: 10s
      init-query-timeout: 10s

datastax.astra:
  secure-connect-bundle: 

astra:
  db:
    id: 
    region: 
    keyspace:  main
    application:
      token:
```